# How to select content from a page without using the text?

Tags: java, html, css, selenium-webdriver

Need to fond out how I can select and click the blog-title without using the text as the content can change frequently.

I do not have a "li" tag so some of the things that I have done before do not work in this case.   Any help would be apprecaited.

Here is the last thing I tried:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//h2[contains(@class, 'blog-post-title')])[3]/a")).click();`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1">
            <span class="pubdate">July 31, 2012</span>

            <h2 class="blog-post-title"><a href=
            "/blogs/roadscholar/the-surprise-attack-and-when-not-to-do-it">The
            Surprise Attack (And When Not to Do It)</a></h2>

            <p class='field-summary'>With 200 meters remaining in the
            250-kilometer Men’s Olympic Road Race last Saturday, Colombia’s
            Rigoberto Uran made a fatal mistake: He turned his head to see what
            was happening behind him....</p><a class="read-more" href=
            "/blogs/roadscholar/the-surprise-attack-and-when-not-to-do-it">Read
            more</a>

            <ul class="links inline">
                <li class="datetime first"><span>Posted at <time class=
                "timestamp" datetime="2012-07-31T17:41:04-04:00">5:41
                PM</time></span></li>

                <li class="disqus_comments_num"><a data-disqus-identifier=
                "node/28978" href=
                "/blogs/roadscholar/the-surprise-attack-and-when-not-to-do-it#disqus_thread">
                Comments</a></li>

                <li class="email"><a class="sharebtn" href=
                "mailto:?subject=The%20Surprise%20Attack%20%28And%20When%20Not%20to%20Do%20It%29&amp;amp;body=With%20200%20meters%20remaining%20in%20the%20250-kilometer%20&amp;lt;a%20href=&amp;quot;http://www.bicycling.com/news/pro-cycling/ahead-pack-vinokourov-sprints-olympic-gold&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Men%E2%80%99s...%20http://stage7.bicycling.com/blogs/roadscholar/the-surprise-attack-and-when-not-to-do-it">
                </a></li>

                <li class="facebook"><a class="sharebtn" href=
                "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[url]=http://stage7.bicycling.com/blogs/roadscholar/the-surprise-attack-and-when-not-to-do-it&amp;p[title]=The%20Surprise%20Attack%20%28And%20When%20Not%20to%20Do%20It%29&amp;p[summary]=With%20200%20meters%20remaining%20in%20the%20250-kilometer%20&amp;lt;a%20href=&amp;quot;http://www.bicycling.com/news/pro-cycling/ahead-pack-vinokourov-sprints-olympic-gold&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Men%E2%80%99s...">
                </a></li>

                <li class="twitter"><a class="sharebtn" href=
                "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=The%20Surprise%20Attack%20%28And%20When%20Not%20to%20Do%20It%29&amp;url=http://stage7.bicycling.com/blogs/roadscholar/the-surprise-attack-and-when-not-to-do-it&amp;via=bicyclingmag">
                </a></li>

                <li class="pinterest"><a class="sharebtn" href=
                "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://stage7.bicycling.com/blogs/roadscholar/the-surprise-attack-and-when-not-to-do-it&amp;description=With%20200%20meters%20remaining%20in%20the%20250-kilometer%20&amp;lt;a%20href=&amp;quot;http://www.bicycling.com/news/pro-cycling/ahead-pack-vinokourov-sprints-olympic-gold&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Men%E2%80%99s...">
                </a></li>

                <li class="googleplus last"><a class="sharebtn" href=
                "https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://stage7.bicycling.com/blogs/roadscholar/the-surprise-attack-and-when-not-to-do-it">
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="views-row views-row-2">
            <span class="pubdate">June 20, 2012</span>

            <h2 class="blog-post-title"><a href=
            "/blogs/roadscholar/advanced-team-construction-capstone-seminar">Advanced
            Team Construction (Capstone Seminar)</a></h2>

            <p class='field-summary'>At some point this week, a selection panel
            consisting of Team Sky managers and coaches will sit down to make a
            difficult decision: which nine of the team’s 28 riders will be in
            Liege, Belgium, on Saturday, June 30th for the start of the 2012
            Tour de France....</p><a class="read-more" href=
            "/blogs/roadscholar/advanced-team-construction-capstone-seminar">Read
            more</a>

            <ul class="links inline">
                <li class="datetime first"><span>Posted at <time class=
                "timestamp" datetime="2012-06-20T22:01:48-04:00">10:01
                PM</time></span></li>

                <li class="disqus_comments_num"><a data-disqus-identifier=
                "node/28977" href=
                "/blogs/roadscholar/advanced-team-construction-capstone-seminar#disqus_thread">
                Comments</a></li>

                <li class="email"><a class="sharebtn" href=
                "mailto:?subject=Advanced%20Team%20Construction%20%28Capstone%20Seminar%29&amp;amp;body=At%20some%20point%20this%20week,%20a%20selection%20panel%20consisting%20of%20&amp;lt;a%20href=&amp;quot;http://www.bicycling.com/tags/team-sky&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Team...%20http://stage7.bicycling.com/blogs/roadscholar/advanced-team-construction-capstone-seminar">
                </a></li>

                <li class="facebook"><a class="sharebtn" href=
                "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[url]=http://stage7.bicycling.com/blogs/roadscholar/advanced-team-construction-capstone-seminar&amp;p[title]=Advanced%20Team%20Construction%20%28Capstone%20Seminar%29&amp;p[summary]=At%20some%20point%20this%20week,%20a%20selection%20panel%20consisting%20of%20&amp;lt;a%20href=&amp;quot;http://www.bicycling.com/tags/team-sky&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Team...">
                </a></li>

                <li class="twitter"><a class="sharebtn" href=
                "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Advanced%20Team%20Construction%20%28Capstone%20Seminar%29&amp;url=http://stage7.bicycling.com/blogs/roadscholar/advanced-team-construction-capstone-seminar&amp;via=bicyclingmag">
                </a></li>

                <li class="pinterest"><a class="sharebtn" href=
                "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://stage7.bicycling.com/blogs/roadscholar/advanced-team-construction-capstone-seminar&amp;description=At%20some%20point%20this%20week,%20a%20selection%20panel%20consisting%20of%20&amp;lt;a%20href=&amp;quot;http://www.bicycling.com/tags/team-sky&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Team...">
                </a></li>

                <li class="googleplus last"><a class="sharebtn" href=
                "https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://stage7.bicycling.com/blogs/roadscholar/advanced-team-construction-capstone-seminar">
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to get the third element with class `blog-post-title` but there are only two such elements. Can you verify your initial xpath or HTML?

Comment: There are more elements but I could not post more.   SO there is a third element.  Just think of that number as being two if you want.  The result is the same.

Comment: Ok, this xpath `//h2[@class='blog-post-title']/a` returns two href elements. Do you need exactly one of them?

Comment: I need only one to prove that the content is there for that block.  But can I Not use the index since it is NOT a list item??   I thought the [3] would get me one to click.   Thanks!!

Comment: If you are not interested in exact item (text) then it can be left as it is. Because WebDriver will click the first found element that matches xpath. I personally hate such not clear solutions but I don't have better one.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can use standard css style selectors such as class and id. E.g.

```
// Class
$('.my-class')
// Id
$('#my-id')
// Element
$('div')
```

And for the clicking...

```
// You don't have to pass event, but it may be useful
$('.my-class').click(function (event) {
    /* Do something */
});
```

Hope this helps. There are a few more that a quick Google search should show you. :)

Comment: Thanks but I am not using jquery I am using Java.  :(

Comment: Lol, I did get a bit confused with the Java & JQuery tags. Sorry I can't help. Hope you get a solution soon. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next query `(//h2[@class='blog-post-title'])[position()=1]` where `position()` specifies number of element which exact needed to be grabbed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with xpath locator by specifying index

```
By.xpath("(//h2[@class='blog-post-title']/a)[3]")
```